# Affect of tem assignment in last for loop

Tags: c++

In the last "for" loop of below code, I expected same output for the assignment of "tem" above the last "for " loop as well as within the last "for" loop. But the outputs are different. Could anyone explain why?

I tried assigning the tem between while and for loop as well as within the last for loop.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;


  void temp(int a[][4],int m,int n,int k){

        int temp[m*n];
        int row=0,col=0;
        int *tem=temp;
        int r=m,l=n;
        int *start=temp;

 while(row<m&&col<n){
                      int *end=start;

   for(int i=row;i<m;i++){

                     *tem=a[i][col];
                    tem++;
                    end++;

                    }col++;
    for(int i=col;i<n;i++){

                     *tem=a[m-1][i];
                    tem++;
                    end++;

                          }m--;

    for(int i=m-1;i>=row;i--){

                            *tem=a[i][n-1];
                                tem++;
                               end++;
                              }n--;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=col;i--){

                          *tem=a[row][i];
                            tem++;
                            end++;
                            }row++;  

    if(end-start>k){reverse(start,k,end-1);

               start=end;
                    }}   
    for(int i=0;i<r*l;i++){ 

                       tem=temp;

                    cout<<*tem<<" ";
                    tem++;


                }


     }
   void reverse(int *start,int k,int *end){
                      int *s=start;
                      int *e=start+k-1;
    while(s<e){ 
        int tem=*s;
        *s=*e;
         *e=tem;
        s++;e--;
        }
                        s=start+k; e=end;
    while(s<e){

                          int tem=*s;
                           *s=*e;
                        s++;e--;
        }
                       s=start; e=end;
    while(s<e){
                        int tem=*s;
                       *s=*e;
                       *e=tem;
                        s++;e--;

        }   


 }



    int main(){

 int b[][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};int j=0;

   temp(b,4,4,3);



   }
```

If the assignment of tem is inside 
13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 
I expected 
13 14 15 16 12 8 4 3 2 1 5 9 7 6 10 11
which is the output if i assign tem between while and for loop.

Comment: `int temp[m*n]` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ require that the number of dimensions are specified by a compile-time constant.  Second, there is already a `std::reverse` -- why not use it?  Third, your code is hard to read due to the poor formatting.

Comment: Also, you are including `vector`, so you should be using it instead of the invalid C++ syntax:  `std::vector<int> temp(m * n);`.

Comment: If you put `tem=temp;` inside the loop then `tem` is going to be assigned so that it points to the beginning of the `temp` array every time round the loop, And so you are always going to see the same value for `*tmp`. But if you put  `tem=temp;` before the loop then `tem` is going to be incremented each time round the loop so you'll see a different value for `*tem`. That seems obvious to me, so I'm a bit unsure why you're confused.

Comment: Your code is not valid C++.  Take your code and attempt to compile it with Visual Studio.  [It will not compile](https://rextester.com/COFRA48055).  Second, if `m` and/or `n` is large, you will get a stack overflow error using such syntax.   Do the correct thing and replace that line with what I mentioned already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code

```
for (int i=0; i<r*l; i++)
{
    tem = temp;
    cout<< *tem << " ";
    tem++;
}
```

`tem` is made to point to the beginning of the `temp` array **each time** around the loop. Because `tem` is always pointing to the beginning of the `temp` array when you print the value of `*tem` you always see the same value output.

But in this code

```
tem = temp;
for (int i=0; i<r*l; i++)
{
    cout << *tem <<" ";
    tem++;
}
```

`tem` is assigned to the beginning of the `temp` array **once only** before the loop. Then in the loop `tem` is incremented so that it points to the next element of the `temp` array. So because `tem` is pointing to a different element of the `temp` array each time round the loop, you see different values printed.